# Assign start button for each file instead of whole queued batch

Tags: fine-uploader

Most of the Fine Uploader documentation seems to only use a single button to begin uploading ALL files which have been added to the queue.  Is there a method which can begin uploading a single file from the queue?

I would like users to be able to add a few files which would be added into a row, and then at the end of each file's row, the user would click a button to begin uploading that individual file.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your situation is simply to construct multiple Fine Uploader instances: one for each row.  At the end of a row, you can have a button that calls the `uploadStoredFiles` method on the corresponding Fine Uploader instance.